# Google Cloud Datastore saves a float without decimals as an int

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Google App Engine app with the following input in a form:

`<input class="form-control" name="num" type="number" step="0.01">`

Then, in the request handler:

```
class NumEntity(ndb.Model):
    num = ndb.FloatProperty()


class AddNum(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        num = self.request.get('num')
        num = float(num.replace(',', '.'))
        new_num = NumEntity(num=num)
        new_num.put()
```

But if I put a number without decimals in the form, it gets stored as an int. Even when I put it with zeros after de comma.

Moreover, when I call `entity.num` on a number that was stored as an int it returns `None`

This only happens in the deployed app, when I run it in the local SDK it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was.

I edited the entities manually in the datastore viewer on the new Developers Console, that, unlike the old one, it treat all numbers as "number" and not as floats and ints. So when I saved the numbers without decimals where stored as ints.

From now on I'm just using the old datastore viewer.